# .$extend JSON objects with varying lengths

Tags: jquery, json

I have two JSON objects.

colJson:

```
{"MetaData": [{"FieldName":"No.","ThousandsSeparator":true},{"FieldName":"Mvmt","DecimalPlaces":0,"ThousandsSeparator":true,"CurrencySymbol":true},{"FieldName":"% Mvmt","DecimalPlaces":1}]}
```

With a length of 3.

rowJson:

```
{"MetaData": [{"BackgroundColour":"#A9A9A9","Bold":true}]}
```

With a length of 1.

What I need is to end up where rowJson is applied to every item in the colJson.

However, when I try this:

```
var jsonObj = {};

jsonObj = $.extend(true, colJson, rowJson);
```

The BackGroundColour and Bold only get applied to the first item in colJson.

Any ideas how to apply BackgroundColour and Bold to all colJson items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal is to use the map and Object.assign functions:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var colJson = {"MetaData": [{"FieldName":"No.","ThousandsSeparator":true},{"FieldName":"Mvmt","DecimalPlaces":0,"ThousandsSeparator":true,"CurrencySymbol":true},{"FieldName":"% Mvmt","DecimalPlaces":1}]};
  var rowJson = {"MetaData": [{"BackgroundColour":"#A9A9A9","Bold":true}]};

  var jsonObj = {"MetaData": colJson.MetaData.map(function(currVal, index, arr) {
    return Object.assign(currVal, rowJson.MetaData[0]);
  })};

  document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, 4, 4);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="result" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></textarea>
```